# Make log4j log in UTC

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to configure my log4j to log in UTC.

I can't find a clear example how to do it. I saw the following thing (but just on one place):

`%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz}{GMT}`

Does that means that after the time format if I add {UTC} I will start to receive logs in UTC or there is something more?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? And [the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) also explains this.

Comment: Well, I don't see it in the documentation. I am not trying this because I have to make the change in 130 files :D

Comment: At the description for `d{pattern}` the docs say: "You can also use a set of braces containing a time zone id per java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone. If no date format specifier is given then the DEFAULT format is used." And it would be easy enough to try this out in a small test project with just one config file.

Comment: Yeah, the small example is always the last thing that comes to my mind, thanks :) But "You can also use a set of braces containing a time zone id per java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone." is pretty unclear. I can use this...for what?

Comment: Exactly what you saw in the example you posted above: `%d{format}{timezone-id}` where in the example you found the timezone id is `GMT`, but you can ofcourse also use another id like `UTC` (by the way, GMT and UTC are practically the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [EnhancedPatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html) then you can use the `{GMT+0}` specifier as per documentation.

If you instead you want to run your application in UTC timezone, you can add the following JVM parameter :

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}{GMT}] %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```